# Python descriptors to chain methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to chain class methods to improve a utility class I've been writing - for reasons I'd prefer not to get into :)

Now suppose I wanted to chain a chain class methods on a class instance (in this case for setting the cursor) e.g.:

```
# initialize the class instance
db = CRUD(table='users', public_fields=['name', 'username', 'email'])

#the desired interface class_instance.cursor(<cursor>).method(...)
with sql.read_pool.cursor() as c:
    db.cursor(c).get(target='username', where="omarlittle")
```

The part that's confusing is I would prefer the cursor not to persist as a class attribute after `.get(...)` has been called and has returned, I'd like to require that `.cursor(cursor)` must be first called.

```
class CRUD(object):
    def __init__(self, table, public_fields):
        self.table = table
        self.public_fields = public_fields

    def fields(self):
        return ', '.join([f for f in self.public_fields])

    def get(self, target, where):
        #this is strictly for illustration purposes, I realize all
        #the vulnerabilities this leaves me exposed to.
        query = "SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {target} = {where}"
        query.format(fields=self.fields, table=self.table, target=target,
                     where=where)
        self.cursor.execute(query)

    def cursor(self, cursor):
        pass  # this is where I get lost.
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "metaprogramming", and why are "descriptors" in the title? There doesn't seem to be any use for any metaprogramming techniques, or for descriptors, in your question or in any likely answer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, what you want is for the `cursor` method to return some object with a `get` method that works as desired. There's no reason the object it returns has to be `self`; it can instead return an instance of some cursor type.

That instance could have a back-reference to self, or it could get its own copy of whatever internals are needed to be a cursor, or it could be a wrapper around an underlying object from your low-level database library that knows how to be a cursor.

If you look at the [DB API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) spec, or implementations of it like the stdlib's [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html), that's exactly how they do it: A `Database` or `Connection` object (the thing you get from the top-level `connect` function) has a `cursor` method that returns a `Cursor` object, and that `Cursor` object has an `execute` method.

So:

```
class CRUDCursor(object):
    def __init__(self, c, crud):
        self.crud = crud
        self.cursor = however_you_get_an_actual_sql_cursor(c)

    def get(self, target, where):
        #this is strictly for illustration purposes, I realize all
        #the vulnerabilities this leaves me exposed to.
        query = "SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {target} = {where}"
        query.format(fields=self.crud.fields, table=self.crud.table, 
                     target=target, where=where)
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        # you may want this to return something as well?

class CRUD(object):
    def __init__(self, table, public_fields):
        self.table = table
        self.public_fields = public_fields

    def fields(self):
        return ', '.join([f for f in self.public_fields])

    # no get method

    def cursor(self, cursor):
        return CRUDCursor(self, cursor)
```

However, there still seems to be a major problem with your example. Normally, after you execute a `SELECT` statement on a cursor, you want to fetch the rows from that cursor. You're not keeping the cursor object around in your "user" code, and you explicitly don't want the `CRUD` object to keep its cursor around, so… how do you expect to do that? Maybe `get` is supposed to `return self.cursor.fetch_all()` at the end or something?

Comment: I don't want to get bogged down in the details of why defining the cursor in the constructor won't work for our architecture, long story short, it wouldn't play nicely with our custom sql context manager.

Comment: @NFicano: I'm _not_ defining the cursor in the constructor of the `CRUD` class, but in the `CRUD.cursor` method, which is exactly where you want it to happen. The key is that whatever state is needed gets stored in the new `CRUDCursor` object, instead of in the `CRUD` object, so that it doesn't persist in the `CRUD` object after the call to `cursor`, which is exactly what you asked for.